# Redirect stdout to Visual Studio output window from native c++ dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli, stdout

I have a c# windows app that calls a managed c++ dll, which, in turn, calls a native c++ dll. There seem to be some performance issues in the native c++ code, so I'm doing some simple profiling. I'd like to dump the results of the profiling so that the Visual Studio output window picks it up. I thought that `printf` would do the trick, but nothing shows up in either the Output window or the Immediate window. I also tried `fprintf`, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [OutputDebugString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362%28VS.85%29.aspx)

OutputDebugString is rather plain, so I tend to add the following to my projects to make it function like printf (making sure to avoid overrunning the buffer size):

```
#if (_VERBOSE)
void DebugPrintf (LPTSTR lpFormat, ...)
{
    TCHAR szBuf[1024];
    va_list marker;

    va_start( marker, lpFormat );
    _vstprintf( szBuf, lpFormat, marker );
    OutputDebugString( szBuf );
    va_end( marker );
}
#endif
```

Comment: +1:  Added benefit of using OutputDebugString(); you can view the messages in DbgView, which means you can view the messages even if your application is running in Release mode and not under the debugger